# How is Pyspark's RandomForestRegressionModel stored in HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm saving a `pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel`
 to HDFS:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor, RandomForestRegressionModel

regresor = RandomForestRegressor(
    maxDepth=16,
    numTrees=100,
    seed=SEED,
    impurity="variance"
)

model = regresor.fit(trainingData)
model.save("random_forest")
```

Listing the contents shows the following output:

```
[username@node ~]$ hdfs dfs -du -h  /user/username/random_forest
70.7 M   212.2 M   /user/username/random_forest/data
509      1.5 K     /user/username/random_forest/metadata
19.6 K   58.7 K    /user/username/random_forest/treesMetadata
```

Each of these directories has a wealth of parquet files. I'm wondering what is stored in each of these directories. Is a complete copy of the training data stored in `/user/username/random_forest/data`?

I'm concerned about how total directory size relates to training data size and model complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model doesn't contain a copy of the training data, but the size depends on the model parameters like the number of trees. Let's have a look at a small example with just 2 trees:

```py
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator

# Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/tmp/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)

data = featureIndexer.transform(data)

# Train a RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="indexedFeatures", numTrees=2)

# Train model. 
model = rf.fit(data)
model.write().overwrite().save('/tmp/randForest')
```

This will generate the following files:
`/tmp/randForest/data`:

- _SUCCESS
- part-00000-c08a27a9-a7d3-47d5-a50d-55cd42ee12f9-c000.snappy.parquet
- part-00001-c08a27a9-a7d3-47d5-a50d-55cd42ee12f9-c000.snappy.parquet

`/tmp/randForest/treesMetadata`:

- _SUCCESS
- part-00000-414aff59-3fac-44d9-8dee-4a334ce41bce-c000.snappy.parquet
- part-00001-414aff59-3fac-44d9-8dee-4a334ce41bce-c000.snappy.parquet

`/tmp/randForest/metadata`:

- _SUCCESS
- part-00000

The output of `model.debugString` is (indentation was added by me):

```py
RandomForestRegressionModel (uid=RandomForestRegressor_7fa55d0ee30d) with 2 trees
 Tree 0 (weight 1.0):
   If (feature 462 <= 62.5)
     Predict: 0.0
   Else (feature 462 > 62.5)
     Predict: 1.0
 Tree 1 (weight 1.0):
   If (feature 405 <= 21.0)
     If (feature 623 <= 253.5)
       Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 623 > 253.5)
       Predict: 1.0
   Else (feature 405 > 21.0)
   If (feature 425 <= 19.0)
     Predict: 1.0
   Else (feature 425 > 19.0)
     Predict: 0.0
```

Let's check the files:

```py
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/randForest/data/part-00000-c08a27a9-a7d3-47d5-a50d-55cd42ee12f9-c000.snappy.parquet").show(truncate=False)
#Output
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|treeID|                                                                                                   nodeData | 
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|0     |[0, 0.5483870967741935, 0.2476586888657648, [93.0, 51.0, 51.0], 0.2476586888657648, 1, 2, [462, [62.5], -1]]| 
|0     |[1, 0.0, 0.0, [42.0, 0.0, 0.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]] | 
|0     |[2, 1.0, 0.0, [51.0, 51.0, 51.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]] | 
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The files in `data` contain parameters which are needed to create a DecisionTreeRegressionModel (nodes, split conditions...)

```py
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/randForest/treesMetadata/part-00000-414aff59-3fac-44d9-8dee-4a334ce41bce-c000.snappy.parquet").show(truncate=False)
#Output
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|treeID|metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |weights|
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|0     |{"class":"org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel","timestamp":1564155036724,"sparkVersion":"2.4.0","uid":"dtr_d963ec77a5ad","paramMap":{},"defaultParamMap":{"checkpointInterval":10,"minInfoGain":0.0,"seed":1366634793,"maxMemoryInMB":256,"maxDepth":5,"impurity":"variance","cacheNodeIds":false,"labelCol":"label","predictionCol":"prediction","maxBins":32,"featuresCol":"features","minInstancesPerNode":1}}|1.0    |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

The files in `treesMetadata` contain the parameters for each single DecisionTreeRegressionModel which were set by you or by default when you called the `fit()` method of the RandomForestRegressor object.

```py
sc.textFile("/tmp/randForest/metadata/part-00000").collect()
#Output:
['{"class":"org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel","timestamp":1564155036257,"sparkVersion":"2.4.0","uid":"RandomForestRegressor_7fa55d0ee30d","paramMap":{"numTrees":2,"featuresCol":"indexedFeatures"},"defaultParamMap":{"maxBins":32,"impurity":"variance","checkpointInterval":10,"numTrees":20,"labelCol":"label","maxDepth":5,"predictionCol":"prediction","featuresCol":"features","minInstancesPerNode":1,"featureSubsetStrategy":"auto","subsamplingRate":1.0,"seed":2502083311556356884,"minInfoGain":0.0,"cacheNodeIds":false,"maxMemoryInMB":256},"numFeatures":692,"numTrees":2}']
```

The file in `metadata` contains the parameters for the RandomForestRegressorModel which were set by you or by default when you called the `fit()` method of the RandomForestRegressor object.